# Need of separate databases and microservices when using Google Cloud Retail AP and Search

Tags: google-cloud-platform, e-commerce

Please note that I'm very new in Retail domain and use of [Google Cloud Retail API](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/retail-product-discovery).

I'm very confused regarding the offerings of Retail from Google cloud. I started using Google Retail for implementation of an e-commerce platform where different Seller can list their product and Buyer can buy.

Now my confusion/question is that can I use the Retail API without my own implementation of services like `inventory`, product `variants`, `cart` etc. If no then how to combine them with my services.

Thanks in advance!